# MSSQL how to open 'Edit' window when databases has been hidden

Tags: sql-server

I hope that someone in here have had this issue before.

THE ISSUE:
- Because 3rd party consultants are doing work to specific customer databases and should not see customer databases to which they have no relation, we have hidden these databases. However, this makes it more cumbersome for the 3rd party consultants, especially the less T-SQL skilled ones.
Specifically I would like to know if it is possible to open the: db --> tables --> right click the specific table --> click 'edit' window....in some other way. Is that possible?

I hope I have made myself clear and I'm looking forward to hear from you.

Thank you in advance.

[image]
resulting in the following window in SQL Management Studio:

[image]

Comment: What are those third party consultants supposed to do once they edit the table? I mean, you hid the database for a good reason I assume?

Comment: Hi @TT - They are supposed to work with the database. For example by using the 'ALTER' keyword (it's just easier to use the gui for some consultants). The user that logs on has db_owner rights on the db's but should not see other db's than the ones he/she is supposed to work with. As this is a shared hosting environment. That is the reason.

Comment: Why not simply create a user that only has access to the databases they're supposed to work on?

Comment: It is not an access issue per say, it is the fact that they should NOT be able to see any other databases, simply because they shouldn't know any other customers running on the system.

Comment: AFAICT if you don't give those users access to other databases, they also won't see them. There is a way to configure it that, try it out.

Comment: @TT Yes they will see them even though they don't have access to them/rights to them. This happens because of the 'View any database'. See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189077(v=sql.105).aspx - this is set per default. If one removes that right for a SQL server user they will not be able to see any databases, unless they are the 'database owner' not to be mistaken for the db_owner right/permission. I'm therefore looking for a way that users will still be able to use the 'Edit All Rows' resulting window, even though the 'view any database' have been removed. See attachments.

Comment: Flagged to move to dba.stackexchange where you are much more likely to get a proper answer.

Comment: Editing data through the 'Edit' window is a hideously bad idea. However I think there is already an answer to this question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120624/hiding-databases-for-a-login-on-microsoft-sql-server-2008r2-and-above

Comment: @TT thank you for moving it here. Likely a more correct forum.

Comment: @MarkSinkinson - Hmmm yes the answer to that question suggests that I should change the owner of the database. I would like not to have to do that. Isn't that possible? Also I aware that it might not be the best way of editing an SQL database. However, the 3rd party consultant doing the editing/maintenance of the database wants to do it this way.

Comment: anyone :-) ????